# Recovery of (possibly) dying SSD

Tags: ntfs

I'm trying to recover an image of an SSD I think may be dying (it's an OCZ Petrol).  It's got Win7 installed at the moment, but I'm using a range of linux tools to try to recover it, hence asking here.  Everything I refer to is obtained from System Rescue CD.

Looking at the SSD in GParted, it's reported as having 98 bad sectors.  Various tools to try and create a backup image have failed as a result of this, including partimage, clonezilla and the simple dd.  Eventually, ntfsclone --rescue succeed in generating a recovery image which I restored to another partition to confirm correct imaging, which it turns out was good.  Looking at that partition though, the bad sectors appear to have come with the image, and that partition is reported as having 98 bad sectors too.  Booting from windows, CHKDISK reports that both partitions are fine and have no problems.

Do I need to be concerned by any of this, or are these bad sector reports essentially "phantom"?  Is some of this perhaps due to incomplete handling of ntfs?

Answer (score 0):

Read this, it should help:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-ntfs/+bug/763155